# How to hide products in frontend in prestashop

Tags: prestashop, hide, product

I want to hide some products from whole the front end of prestashop and only they must be visible by the link and nowhere else !

Is it possible ?

thank you

Comment: [Why we're not customer support for \\[your favorite company\\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)

Comment: This is not about programming and is **off topic** as described in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can, go to product admin page then (in prestashop 1.7) in Options tab, just make change Visibility to "Nowhere". So it won't be displayed anywhere except if you have the url.

Comment: That was great,thank for solution :)

Comment: Please put this answer as "solved" :)

Comment: tab's name is alternative.